# Infimum of a multivariable function

Tags: real-analysis, limits, optimization

How to find the infimum of following equation over y.

$$f(x,y)=x^T Ax+x^T By+y^T Bx+y^T Cy$$
$$inf_y f(x,y)=?$$

where A and C are symetric matrices

Comment: Are $A,B,C$ symmetric matrices? Positive definite?

Comment: @ChristopherA.Wong yes A, and C are symetric no information about B..

Comment: you can rewrite $f(x,y)=(x^T,y^T)\left(\matrix{A & B\\B & C}\right)\left(\matrix{x\\y}\right)$.

Comment: @Easy It is a matix representation. I want to find the infimum.

Comment: got the answer..we have to use schur complement..but still not satisfied. i want to know how to solve without using schur complement

Answer (score 1):

The function $f$ is convex in $y$ if $C$ is positive semidefinite (otherwise, the infimum is $-\infty$, dominated by $y^TCy$). Therefore, the infimum is attained where the derivative with respect to $y$ is zero. The derivative is $x^T(B+B^T)+Cy+y^TC$. Equating this to zero, you get a linear system for $y^*$ (with unique solution if $C$ is positive definite, otherwise any solution will do). Then plug into $f$. Since $y^*$ is a linear function of $x$, the infimal value will be a quadratic polynomial in $x$.